# Alternate to $Resource in Angular 2, 400 bad request

Tags: http, angular, asp.net-web-api

**Angular 1 service**
I am migrating my application from `angular 1` to `angular 2`. 
This angular 1 service call is working fine and getting back the response

```
 "getUserResource": function () {
                        return $resource(basePath + "api/v3/user/GetUser/:name", { name: "@name",password: "@password"}, {
                            get: { method: "GET", isArray: true }
                        });
                    },
```

**Angular 2**
This angular 2 call is not hitting the `web Api` controller and it gives a `400 bad request` error

```
getUserResourcePromise(): Promise<User[]> {
        let params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('name', 'test');
        params.set('password', 'test');
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/v3/user/GetUser/:name', { search: params.toString(), headers: this.headers })
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data as User[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

**Angular 1 vs Angular 2 URL's**

```
http://localhost:58999/api/v3/user/GetUser/test?password=test(angular 1 url)
http://localhost:58999/api/v3/user/GetUser/:name?name=test&password=test(angular 2 url)
```

**web api controller**

Can anyone please tell me how to make the angular 2 URL to hit this controller, what changes do I have to make?

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/v3/user")]

 [HttpGet]
     [ResponseType(typeof(UsersModel))]
     [Route("GetUser/{name}")]
     public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUser(string name,string password) {
     }
```

Comment: Are you able to successfully test the GET request using Angular 2 URL from Postman?

Comment: no the angular 2 url which i am building is wrong, can any one tell me how to build the right url(which is http://localhost:58999/api/v3/user/GetUser/test?password=test) in angular 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have to hardcode your url...

```
getUserResourcePromise(): Promise<User[]> {
        let querystring = 'test?password=test'
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/v3/user/GetUser/'+queryString, {headers: headers})
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data as User[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

And if you are using variables the `queryString` would of course look something like this:

```
let queryString = username+'?password'+password
```